# Локаль для MSBuild в cygwin

Tags: bash, locale, cygwin

В cygwin набор символов установлен в utf8. Как можно задать его в cp866 перед запуском определенного приложения, например MSBuild?

`LANG="ru_RU.cp866" MSBuild.exe /?`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `LC_ALL="ru_RU.cp866"` тоже не работает?  `LC_ALL="C"` и работать на английском? `locale -a` что-нить путное выводит? А если `CP` капсом?

Comment: `LC_ALL="ru_RU.cp866"` не работает,  в настройках cygwin стоит C.utf8. `locale -a` cp866 в списке не показывает, однако в настройках cygwin набор cp866 есть, и если его выставить - вывод win приложений нормализуется, но ломается вывод команд (ls, к примеру).